# Is there a lighter version of Rstudio available?

Tags: r, rstudio, jupyter-lab

I like using `Rstudio` and mostly work with notebooks like `Rmarkdown` files but unfortunately I have to work on an old system which doesn't have much of ram and computation power.

I have noticed `pandoc` eats up alot of resource in my system so I have started working back on `jupyter lab` even for R and it works smoothly.

But with `jupyter` for R kernel it has its own challenges like no shortcut for `%>%`, no tool tip etc.

So is there a lighter version of Rstudio available ?

Comment: @Roland unfortunately that's what my pocket allow right now so I just trying to figure out what could be the best possible way to work with notebooks

Comment: I was not referring to your pockets. I was referring to the cost in computing resources.

Comment: You don't need Rstudio to render Rmarkdown files. You can do it directly with `Rscript`.

Comment: @Roland, yea i got your point but if you see even in `python` there is `pycharm` and `jupyter notebook/labs`. If pycharm is heavy weight then jupyters are lighter, easier to work with specially for notebooks and they have extensions which one can add as per the requirement.

Comment: @sindri_baldur well I am new in R and still learning so thats why I prefer progressing with notebooks as its easier with notebooks to go back and refer notebooks with outcomes. I guess I can't have best of all !!

Comment: JupyterLab now supports `>%>` and `<-` (and all other) shortcuts, you just need to enable them, see https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10114#issuecomment-821993321

Comment: As for the tooltips in JupyterLab those can be enabled with: https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitations of JupyterLab you mention can be overcome:

- tooltip and other coding assistance functions can be enabled by installing (my) extension [jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp)
- custom shortcuts like for inserting `>%>` and `<-` can be [easily enabled](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10114#issuecomment-821993321), pasting the following in the `Keyboard Shortcut` settings (see link for more details):

  ```
    {
        "command": "apputils:run-first-enabled",
        "selector": "body",
        "keys": ["Alt -"],
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "console:replace-selection",
                "fileeditor:replace-selection",
                "notebook:replace-selection",
            ],
            "args": {"text": "<- "}
        }
    },
    {
        "command": "apputils:run-first-enabled",
        "selector": "body",
        "keys": ["Accel Shift M"],
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "console:replace-selection",
                "fileeditor:replace-selection",
                "notebook:replace-selection",
            ],
            "args": {"text": ">%> "}
        }
    }
  ```

The truth is though that adding extensions will not make JupyterLab lighter. As both RStudio and JupyterLab are built for similar use-case, they will be growing to accommodate the needs of users (as much as the improvements in hardware performance will allow).

Both applications support an extension/plugin system which allows you to enable or disable additional functions. Possibly the most interesting approach is that taken by [retrolab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/retrolab) which takes a subset of the JupyterLab components and arranges them for the look and feel of the old Jupyter Notebook interface. You can do the same (see [example app](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/master/examples/app) which is built from ground up using only a minimal subset of JuptyterLab components), or just disable some extensions that are enabled by default).

Comment: Thankyou @krassowki for sharing the alternative solution in  detail. Really appreciate it. I think I tried adding the shortcut to jupyterlab that time when I made this post but it was not working so then I achieved this by creating shortcut in windows instead. I will try your code from here and if I will face any challenge then I will let you know. Thanks again really appreciate it :))

Answer (score 3):

A possibility for using RStudio on a system without many resources is to run the server version on a good system, and access it over the net.

Setting up the server isn't trivial, but you may be able to use https://rstudio.cloud.  It's free for small projects (up to 15 hours per month).  If you're an instructor at an accredited institution, the prices are pretty low.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the issue I am facing as I am new in Programming world with a bit of knowledge in Python and R. It was easy for me to start with python as there is good support for Python from google colab and lighter jupyter. 

But in R these limited time option in Rstudio are the challenges (15hours I will eat up in just 1-2 days .. :) ). 
Though Google colab works for R but doesn't support shortcuts `%>%`  and few more things.

Comment: It's almost always worthwhile to put extra RAM in an old machine.  If it's older and not already maxed out, this will probably be pretty cheap.  Or, you could just give up on notebooks and use some other IDE for R:  one that comes with it, or ESS in Emacs, etc.

Comment: well my previous company builds super computers and we always had access to HPC so never had such issues but now for my personal work I am actually waiting for the latest CPU's & GPU's to come up in the market as lots of announcements were expected in October. I guess its couple of months more that I will have to suffer. And I am thinking of using Emacs too. I guess that is last resort for me if nothing else works

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not, man... I think RStudio Desktop should features optional. At least those that are heavier. So user who doesn't need Git/Connections/Environment browser, rmarkdown preview, or many others, They could simply disable those ones.

Comment: I totally agree with you @Augusto Pohl. Same is in `Jupyter lab/`.They have extensions which one can add as per their need. It's perfect for Python but not for R